# How to 'steal' data from QByteArray without copy

Tags: qt

Is it possible to take pointer to `QByteArray`'s internal `T* data` and destroy `QByteArray` itself so that the pointer remains unreleased? I would like to use it in the something similar to the following scenario:

```
const char* File::readAllBytes(const String& path, u64& outCount) {
    QFile file(*static_cast<QString*>(path.internal()));
    outCount = static_cast<u64>(file.size());
    if (!file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly)) gException("Failed to open file");
    const QByteArray array = file.readAll();
    return array.steal();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can't steal `QByteArray`'s pointer unless it has been constructed with `QByteArray::fromRawData`, which is not the case. However you can create char array manually and read data from file to it using `QFile::read(char * data, qint64 maxSize)`. You will then decide where to pass the pointer and when to `delete[]` it.

Note that this is not considered good practice. You should use managed allocations whenever you can, and Qt provides enough to cover most of possible use cases. You should not do this unless you're trying to do something really low-level.

Note that many of Qt classes, including `QString` and `QByteArray`, use copy-on-write strategy, so you generally should not be afraid of copying them and passing them to another context.

Answer (score 0):

No, but you can easily sidestep the problem by not using `QByteArray`:

```
const char* File::readAllBytes(const String& path, u64& outCount) {
    QFile file(*static_cast<QString*>(path.internal()));
    if (!file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly)) return nullptr;
    auto N = file.bytesAvailable();
    char *data = malloc(N);
    outCount = file.read(data, N);
    return data;
}
```

The solution above  also assumes that the consumer of your data is aware of the need to `free` the data.

Alas, the manual memory management called for with such an API is a bad idea. If you wish not to use Qt classes in your API, you should be using `std::vector<char>` instead:

```
std::vector<char> File::readAllBytes(const String& path) {
    std::vector<char> result;
    QFile file(*static_cast<QString*>(path.internal()));
    if (!file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly)) return result;
    result.resize(file.bytesAvailable());
    auto count = file.read(result.data(), result.size());
    result.resize(count);
    return result;
}
```

I smell that `String` is some sort of a framework-independent string wrapper. Perhaps you could settle on `std::u16string` to carry the same UTF16 data as `QString` would.